# Expand div horizontally using css

Tags: css, html, autoresize

I am looking to expand a div horizontally after a video is dynamically resized, similar to how YouTube works on re-sizing.

I have re-sizing images on the video and they work fine, users can press the + or - arrow fine and the video resizes, but the box on the right does not fall below it and expand the 100% of 1024px container (the max the video resizes). Also, when the video is reduced in size the box does not expand to the left.

Can anyone help me on this?

Please take a look at my jsFiddle as an example http://jsfiddle.net/headex/Xw8EV/ (*NOTE*: *The images for the resizing buttons are not in the fiddle, you just have to imagine they are there*)

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `diplay: inline-block` for container element. In that case you do not have to define the width for it and it will have the size of inner element.

Comment: Likewise, if the container is floated with no explicit width, it will be shrink-wrapped to the size of its content.